# How use "transcludeControllers" in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, compilation

I want use the "transcludeControllers" property present as argument of $compile function of angular (at the end of https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile page )
I've some problem.
I made a jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/qq4gqn6t/5/

```
$element.append($compile('<son></son>')($scope, undefined, {
    transcludeControllers: {
        dad: this
    }
}));
```

But it does not seem to work

Work only if I uncomment the 42 row

```
//templateUrl: 'sonTemplate.html'
```

Another solution is

```
https://jsfiddle.net/qq4gqn6t/6/
```

Have some ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had resolved 
https://jsfiddle.net/qq4gqn6t/11/